# Split DNS no longer working when installing mobileconfig VPN profile

Tags: network, vpn, dns

My company uses Split DNS to resolve internal domains. We configure this Split DNS by installing a mobileconfig with a VPN profile. See also https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf for more information.

The profile contains the following section:

```xml
<key>SupplementalMatchDomains</key>
<array>
  <string>cb.local</string>
  <string>privatelink.azurewebsites.net</string>
</array>
```

Usually this would configure/install the following resolvers, output from `scutil --dns` where resolver #1 is the one provided by the local network:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : cb.local
  search domain[1] : privatelink.azurewebsites.net
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.0.1
  if_index : 14 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  domain   : cb.local
  nameserver[0] : 10.233.3.17
  nameserver[1] : 10.233.3.27
  if_index : 23 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Supplemental, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
  order    : 103000
...

resolver #4
  domain   : privatelink.azurewebsites.net
  nameserver[0] : 10.233.3.17
  nameserver[1] : 10.233.3.27
  if_index : 23 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Supplemental, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
  order    : 103001
...

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.0.1
  if_index : 14 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : cb.local
  nameserver[0] : 10.233.3.17
  nameserver[1] : 10.233.3.27
  if_index : 23 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

However this is no longer the case:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.0.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
...

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 172.16.0.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : cb.local
  nameserver[0] : 10.233.3.17
  nameserver[1] : 10.233.3.27
  if_index : 18 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

I have tried reinstalling the mobileconfig Profile and restarting the machine to no avail:

```
> ping ad01.cb.local
ping: cannot resolve ad01.cb.local: Unknown host
```

How can I get Split DNS to work again? I really want to configure it through a profile (`.mobileconfig`) (and not through various `/etc/resolver/domain` files or a local `dnsmasq` instance).

macOS Ventura 13.0.1.

Comment: What kind of VPN is it?

Comment: @not2savvy it's a IKEv2 VPN (road warrior).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I can confirm that this particular split DNS setup doesn't longer work on macOS Ventura as of version 13.3 at least.

I used the latest available version of Apple Configurator to recreate the VPN (IKEv2) profile. Still, split DNS doesn't work.

Does anybody know why, and how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/335919)